# Entropy Balancing and regression

Tags: regression, matching

I have a panel data set consisting of a treatment and a control group. The control group contains much more observations than the treatment group. In order to adjust some specific Variables between both groups, I generated weights using entropy balancing in Stata.

Now, I am about to find the right model to estimate the effect of the treatment. I was wondering, if it is possible to take the same variables, that were used for the balancing, into the regression model.

I would appreciate a small comment on that.
Thanks!

Kind regards,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using linear regression after EB, the effect estimate will not change if include the variables that were balanced or not. This is demonstrated in the original paper on EB ([Hainmueller, 2012](https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpr025)) and the reason is explained in [Chattopadhyay and Zubizarreta (2022)](http://arxiv.org/abs/2104.06581). So, you can include include the variables, but there is no reason to. For a nonlinear model, including the variables balanced in EB might change the coefficients, and therefore any marginal effects estimated from the model. To estimate the standard error of the treatment effect estimate, you should bootstrap the process of estimating the entropy balancing weights and estimating the treatment effect.

Comment: Noah, thank you so much for your extent answer! I just read Hainmuellers documentation about the EB-Stata-function. The paper you recommended, helps me a lot! Maybe you also have an answer to another question: I have time-dummy’s inside the model, so I get the years displayed in the regression table. If I assume right, they just catch the time-invariant effects. So I suppose I don’t have to interpret them?

Comment: That's right. If you use `xtreg` they won't even show up.

Comment: Sorry for digging the question out again, but Noah, on which page have you found that in Hainmueller 2012? I just had a case where the effect changes by including variables that were balanced

Comment: The final paragraph on page 41 and the final paragraph on page 43.

Comment: Thank you, Noah, for your fast response! I am a bit confused, aren't that just the differences in means to show the impact of EB compared to other methods? I actually have the problem, that by including variables, that I before used for reweighting the control group, in the regression, the coefficients are changing.

Comment: The paper demonstrates that when one million regressions are fit with the same variables used in the weighting, the effect estimates are identical. Are you doing a linear regression or some other kind? Are you including squares or interactions of covariates in your model that you didn't include in the weights? Did entropy balancing successfully balance the means of the variables you included?

Comment: I  am doing a linear FE regression. I include one interaction term of treat*after to measure the effect of a treatment. Both variables are not included in weights. EB successfully balanced the means in terms of treatment and control group are nearly equal